# Android - search based on property of AutoCompleteTextView suggestion, or value of AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a `MyObj` class with a `name` and an `id`.  I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` that is currently letting you type `MyObj` names and it auto-completes them for you.  There's a button next to the `AutoCompleteTextView` that, when pressed, I want to:

- initiate a search based on the `id` of the selected `MyObj`, if one of the auto-complete suggestions was used, *OR*
- initiate a search based on the value in the `AutoCompleteTextView` if none of the auto-complete suggestions was used (so a partial `name` string).

How should I go about this?  I'm new to Android, so suggestions for other ways to do this are very welcome.  Here's some of my current code:

```
AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.searchText);
ArrayAdapter<MyObj> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyObj>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, myObjectsList);
actv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And also:

```
public void searchButtonOnClick(View view) {
    // Don't know how to get id of selected MyObj here, or just the value in the
    // AutoCompleteTextView otherwise
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a [search](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) instead of using an `AutoCompleteTextView`, since the search gives suggestions as you type also.  I was able to pass the `id` along via the URI in an `Intent` to display another `Activity` with the `MyObj` details.